# Instantiate standalone Vue.js app (2.0.0rc7) with properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app (2.0.0rc7) that is built using single page components. The main component is called `App`. To render my application into a div with id `app`, I use the following script (I called it `main.js`):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

This approach works well. I am using webpack to resolve imports. However, I would like my application be be used as a "drop-in" that developers can easily use within their websites. Therefore, I wonder, how can I pass properties to the main `App` component?

For example, I would like to enable developers to load my (built) app using HTML script tags and then instantiate it using:

```
App(dataObj1, dataObj2, ..., '#id-of-div-element-to-mount')
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... Please provide use case or something.

Comment: Suggestion to improve your question: at least provide a sample code of how you want your thing to be used by developers.

Comment: Sure, I added an example to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem: I created an `init` function that takes as input the desired data and then renders the application to an HTML element. I make this init function available in the global namespace:

```
var init = function (data, el) {
  const vm = new Vue({
    el: el,
    template: '<app :data="data"/>',
    components: {
      App
    },
    data () {
      return {
        data: data
      }
    }
  })
}

// grab existing namespace object, or create a blank object
// if it doesn't exist
var APP = window.APP || {}
APP = {
  init: init
}
window.APP = APP
```

This way, others can use my built application with their data in their HTML pages via `APP.init(data, '#some-el-id')`.

For this to work, Vue needs to be built in the standalone mode, which requires to add this to the webpack config:

```
// ...
resolve: {
    alias: {vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'}
},
// ...
```

See details here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/wiki/Vue-2.0-RC-Starter-Resources#standalone-vs-runtime-builds